# e.t[missing-dot] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [e.t](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e.t) tag is malformed if one looks closely.

It appears that tags cannot be created(or renamed) to end in punctuation.  This seems almost too trivial to bring up; but, as every other acronym-as-tag has no periods (e.g., [dcau](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dcau), [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), [ai](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai), [rpg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg)), it sticks out a bit as a sore thumb.

I'm somewhat of the mind that [et](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/et) looks awry, but it was suggested on chat that I post for opinions.  Rename or no?  And is it absolutely impossible to allow tags to end in '.'?

Comment: `et` is certainly better than nothing.  But why not `et-the-extra-terrestial`?

Comment: @MatthewRead I would hate to perpetuate unnecessary redundancies unnecessarily.

Comment: The word is spelled terrestRial, folks. I don't really have an opinion one way or the other about what this tag should be called, but if y'all decide to create the longer-named tag, please make sure to spell it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [et-the-extra-terrestrial](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/et-the-extra-terrestrial) (as suggested by [Matthew Read](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/e-tmissing-dot-tag#comment8892_2799) in the comments) would be the least ambiguous one and both [e.t](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e.t) and [et](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/et) should by synonyms. An alternative would have been [e.t.-the-extra-terrestrial](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e.t.-the-extra-terrestrial) but the period followed by the hyphen looks weird, so I still vote for the very first one.

This makes the meaning of what the "et" stands for more clear.

Edit: Typo fixed as per [Martha](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/e-tmissing-dot-tag/2803?noredirect=1#comment8911_2799)'s suggestion.

Comment: I like [tag:et-the-extra-terrestrial] because "E.T." is a generic term in addition to the title of the film.  See [tag:aliens] vs [tag:aliens-1986].

Comment: A meta-Meta question- who am I to 'accept' an answer here?  Do I simply wait a customary period of time and 'accept' the most-upvoted?

Comment: @Solemnity: Consensus is not defined strictly. However, you can accept an answer that you think works best for you, but the community might disagree. If there is enough consensus (which at the moment doesn't seem to be the case) it will become a policy and the tags will be changed (probably by a mod).

Comment: Done. [tag:e.t.-the-extra-terrestrial] is one character too long anyway, so [tag:et-the-extra-terrestrial] it is.

Answer (score 1):

[et](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/et) looks awry because unlike many acronyms, it is pronounceable. I prefer [e.t](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e.t) to [et](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/et). While [e.t](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e.t) would be better, I doubt that it's important enough for us to get an exception to the tag naming rules.

Alternatively, we could write [e-t](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-t), following the habit of using a hyphen as the word separator.

Comment: Do you know which set of characters is allowed for tags? Maybe there can be something found that resembles E.T.

Comment: @bitmask Lowercase Latin letters, digits and `#.-+`